# Вменяемый поиск по hub.docker.com

Tags: docker

Суть проблемы: как ориентироваться в результатах поиска с https://hub.docker.com/ ?

- фильтрация по популярности выводит не самые скачиваемые образы без звезд ([пример](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=bitrix&type=image)), я бы не назвал это "популярным"
- многие образы не содержат ни `README`, ни `Dockerfile`, имеют кучу звезд и скачек, но не ясно как ими пользоваться, и что "внутри" без скачивания и исследования файловой системы
- нередко образы не соответствуют тому, что заявлено

Такое ощущение, что это помойка.

Как можно найти более-менее вменяемые образы? Может быть, есть альтернативы поиску?

Answer (score 0):

Как Вам такой вариант?

```
docker search tomcat
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В первую очередь будут показаны официальные и имеющие наибольшее количество звёзд images.

Comment: Тот же самый поиск, что https://hub.docker.com/ , обозначенные проблемы не решает