# Есть ли API для получения информации по образам из хаба hub.docker.com

Tags: docker

Есть [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/search/?type=image), в котором 2 418 215 образов.

Цель: сделать вменяемый поиск по образам, так как их поиск меня не устраивает, я тут уже [задавал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998618/%d0%92%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-hub-docker-com)

Как я это вижу: скачать всю мета-информацию по образам (автор, README, количество звезд, etc) по некоторому API (который я ищу), загнать в БД и сделать свой поиск. Как минимум, я хочу добавить свойства "есть README.md", "есть репозиторий на гитхабе" - эти два параметра отсеят то, что непонятно как использовать.

Есть ли подобный API, документация?

Comment: изучали api docker'a ?

Comment: @Dmitry , пожалуйста, покажите ссылку на это

Comment: тут есть инфа по api и sdk https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, меня сильно смущает то, что описана дока по версии 2, а если идти на хаб, там используется версия 1, и не понятно какая именно: `https://hub.docker.com/api/content/v1/products/search?page_size=25&q=squid&type=image`. Это норм? Плюс есть какие-нибудь особенности, типа лимитов? И является ли документация по ссылке той же, что используется на hub.docker.com ?

Comment: @Dmitry, по ссылке документация по API для управления докером: `The SDKs allow you to build and scale Docker apps and solutions quickly and easily.`. Мне же нужно вытащить репозиторий с описанием. Думаю, это не подходит.

Comment: url [другой](https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/): `$ curl -i https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, добавил ответ. они отключили каталог. есть еще идеи? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Краткий ответ: API есть, но вытащить через него не получится

Разбираемся.

Описание API есть: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

> The catalog for a given registry can be retrieved with the following request: GET /v2/_catalog

Мой скрипт для получения списка образов:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN=`curl -sS "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io" | jq -r ".token"`

set -x
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/_catalog"
set +x
```

Он получает такие данные:

```
{"status_code": "404", "error": "The requested URL (/v2/_catalog) was not found on this server."}
```

Как сказано тут на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082826/insufficient-scope-when-attempting-to-get-docker-hub-catalog/37518393#37518393), на hub.docker.com они отключили каталог, поэтому таким способом получить образы не получится.